# document is not getting updated properly in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My mongodb document is as shown below.

```
{"studid":"123", "name":"abc"}
```

I want to update this document as follows.

```
{"studid":"123", "name":"abc", "class":"five", "sec":"b"}
```

To achieve this i have written code as follows and passing query and field as.

name - `"studreg"`, query - `{"studid":"123"}` and field - `"class":"five", "sec":"b"`

```
exports.modify = function(name,query,field) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var updateStr = '{$set:{'+field+'}}';
        console.log('updateStr: ' + updateStr);
        dbase.collection(name,function(err,table){
            table.findAndModify(query,[[_id,desc]],updateStr,{w:1, new:true},function(err,result){
                if (err) reject(err);
                else
                    resolve(result);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

As output i am getting following message printed on my browser window when i am invoking modify method.

```
{"lastErrorObject":{"updatedExisting":true,"n":1},"value":{"_id":"585ce7d9bef96722642adfeb"},"ok":1}
```

In database when i try to find the document it is showing only the id field and not any other fields. Can you let me know where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. As Rahul mentioned problem is with parsing the updateStr. When i used JSON.parse('{\"$set\":{'+field+'}}') and JSON.parse(query) while invoking the method, i got the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#example)

It says that the `update` field must be object, not `string` as you used.

So your input field must be field- `{"class":"five", "sec":"b"}`

Try like this

```
exports.modify = function(name,query,field) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var updateObj = {$set: field}; //field must be object
        console.log('updateStr: ' + updateStr);
        dbase.collection(name,function(err,table){
            table.findAndModify(query,[['_id','desc']],updateObj,{upsert: true},function(err,result){
                if (err) reject(err);
                else
                    resolve(result);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

And one more thing I didn't see the `_id`, a mandatory field for `mongodb document` in your given `document`.

Comment: What about this `_id` field in document ?

Comment: _id field get added automatically when we insert the document right?

Comment: i do not have any errors but except id field all other fields are getting removed instead of updating thme

Answer (score 0):

I think the analysis by Jyothi is correct, but the field is coming as a string and needs to be converted as an object. In my opinion just create the updateStr as in question and then use JSON.parse(updateStr) to get the object version of that.

```
exports.modify = function(name,query,field) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var updateStr = '{$set:{'+field+'}}';
        console.log('updateStr: ' + updateStr);
        var updateObj = JSON.parse(updateStr);
        dbase.collection(name,function(err,table){
            table.findAndModify(query,[[_id,desc]],updateObj,{w:1, new:true},function(err,result){
                if (err) reject(err);
                else
                    resolve(result);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

And the fact that it is removing all other variables but _id just proves to the point that your updateStr is not parsed as it should be.

Comment: I tried both the options mentioned in your comment. But it is still not working. Moreover, the filed variable is being used in updateStr which is encapsulated in { }. I tried using JSON.parse for both query as well as updateStr while invoking findAndModify. Still it is not working.I am not getting any error except the message shown in my above post.